# Strange / esoteric join syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, syntax

I've been provided this old SQL code (table names changed) to replicate, and the JOIN syntax isn't something I've seen before, and is proving hard to google:

```
select <stuff>

from A

inner join B
on A.ID = B.A_ID

inner join C  -- eh? No ON?

inner join D
ON C.C_ID = D.C_ID

ON B.C_ID = D.C_ID -- a second ON here? what?
```

When I saw the code, I assumed I'd be sent broken code and it wouldn't run.

But it does. (Sql Server 2012)

What does it do? Is there a more sensible / standard way of writing it? What's happening here?

Comment: check there where clause... it's using old ansi-89 style joins combined with proper joins i suspect

Comment: There's no where clause, this is the entire query :)

Comment: This is valid syntax.  It's just another (terrible) way of writing two `JOIN`s next to each other.  The more sensible way of writing this is by putting the `ON` clause next to the appropriate `JOIN`.  The only advantage (if you can call it an advantage) is that it illustrates that you want to `JOIN` `B` to `C`, by proxy of `D`.  But honestly... just write it out.  It'll be less confusing for everyone involved.

Comment: not as simple as just putting the second ON next to the C join, as it uses D in the join condition. And can't move `inner join D` up above `inner join C`, as it uses C. I don't think there's an order of "regular style" joins that doesn't cause a binding error

Comment: Or change the join order so the compiler doens't error A-->B-->D-->C and no need for ()'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While unusual, this is perfectly valid tsql. Typically you see this approach when you have an outer join to a set of related tables which are inner joined to one another. A better IMHO way to write this would be:

```
inner join B
   on A.ID = B.A_ID
inner join (C inner join D ON C.C_ID = D.C_ID) 
   ON B.C_ID = D.C_ID
```

This makes the join logic clear - and it also helps the reader. Additionally, it lets the reader know that the developer did this intentionally. So let this be an example of poor coding. Comment things that are unusual. Explain things. Have someone review your code periodically to help improve your style and usage.

And you could write this in a "typical" style by rearranging the order of tables in the from clause - but I'll guess that the current version makes more logical sense with the real table names.

Comment: It's not my code, its old legacy code I was sent to work on and the syntax threw me. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran it by a colleague who figured it out:

```
select <stuff>

from A

inner join B
on A.ID = B.A_ID

inner join ( C  -- put a bracket here...

inner join D
ON C.C_ID = D.C_ID

) -- and one here

ON B.C_ID = D.C_ID
```

or to format it a little nicer:

```
select <stuff>

from A

inner join B
on A.ID = B.A_ID

inner join ( 
    C
    inner join D
    ON C.C_ID = D.C_ID
)
ON B.C_ID = D.C_ID
```

I wasn't familiar with this kind of "sub-join" (I don't know what it's called), but this is much more readable and clear

Comment: Personally I'd just move D before C, that's even cleaner IMO... A-->B-->D-->C and no need for ()'s

Comment: The join condition for D relies on C - A-B-D-C order creates a binding error

Comment: `from A
inner join B
  on A.ID = B.A_ID
inner join D
  ON B.C_ID = D.C_ID 
inner join C  
  ON C.C_ID = D.C_ID` doens't that achieve the same results?